# Java DNS Lookup for SRV records

Tags: java, dns, srv

In the below java code, I am making a DNS SRV record lookup to resolve the target domain name and associated port for a given domain name such as root@1000000000.blubluzone.com. The lookup function indicated with /*HERE*/ below returns null somehow and I cannot get a a query result (i.e. record array is null). As a consequence, a null pointer exception is thrown when records array is accessed in the for loop.

What do you think I am missing to make the following code work. I am using using dnsjava and the related API jar file is available at http://www.dnsjava.org/download/  (at the bottom of the page). Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

```
     import org.xbill.DNS.Lookup;
     import org.xbill.DNS.Record;
     import org.xbill.DNS.SRVRecord;
     import org.xbill.DNS.TextParseException;
     import org.xbill.DNS.Type;

     public class DNSLookup {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

          if (args.length < 1) {
             System.err.println("Usage: java -jar DNSLookup <hostname>");
             System.exit(1);
          }

          String query = "_ssh._tcp." + args[0];

          try {
            /*****HERE*********/
            Record[] records = new Lookup(query, Type.SRV).run();

            for (Record record : records) {
                 SRVRecord srv = (SRVRecord) record;

            String hostname = srv.getTarget().toString().replaceFirst("\\.$", "");
            int port = srv.getPort();

            System.out.println(hostname + ":" + port);
          }
          } catch (TextParseException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
      }
```

Comment: If you'd like to run this code 8 years later, when the linked .jar file turns out to be 404 status page, you can use the dependency available in Maven repo: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dnsjava/dnsjava

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine, except that `Lookup.run()` returns `null` (**not** an empty array) if no records are found.

For example, if you replace `_ssh._tcp` with `_nicname._tcp` and then look up `uk` you'll find an SRV record for the .UK `whois` server.

If there's a problem it's with your input parameters.