# Retrieving DNS SRV records on Android using service name

Tags: android, dns, srv, dnsjava

On android I want to find list of records just by using service name. I have tried api's like dnsjava and jmdns but all returned empty results. I have come across this similar Question but no one has answered it either:

[Lightweight way to resolve DNS SRV records on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661522/lightweight-way-to-resolve-dns-srv-records-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dnsjava library and use its Lookup class for that purpose.
Like:

String recordName = _name._tcp.domainName.;

Lookup lookup = new Lookup(recordName, Type.SRV);

Records recs[] = lookup.run();