# Manage DNS records in Scala language

Tags: scala, dns, akka, srv-record

I'm asking if I can check the type of DNS records, in particular if they are A records or SRV. Furthermore, how can I manage the SRV records with Akka HTTP through Scala code. There is [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/io-dns.html#srv-records) about that but can you provide an example?
Currently, I use

```
ipList = InetAddress.getAllByName(nameServer)
```

to fetch the list of IP Addresses associated to that name, with A Records (myserver.geo.server.com.     IN  A   10.58.203.190) it works correctly.
But I noticed that if I add also an SRV Records (ex. _thrift._tcp.prova.geo.server.com.          IN SRV 10 0 9095 myserver.geo.server.com.
), this code is not able to fetch that records.

So I think I have to use another approach, I read documentation linked above but I did'nt understand how to use it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "manage"?

Comment: Added more information in post

Comment: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.6.16/akka-docs/src/test/scala/docs/actor/io/dns/DnsCompileOnlyDocSpec.scala

Comment: Alternatively, if you're not inclined to bring in Akka just for resolving SRV records, this Java question may be a reasonable guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138844/java-dns-lookup-for-srv-records